# get a table in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

For some reasons, I'd like to know how can I add a table in a sharepoint list

I remember that I did once during my studies but I can't remember how to do that, any idea?

Comment: In my opinion you are confused, maybe you need an datasheet view, where you can work with items in the table version? 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-list-view-in-sharepoint-online-d51d74b4-573d-4cf3-a872-fdb8ab2b48a6

Comment: perhaps you meant you wanted to import an SQL table?  If you could update your answer to be a bit more specific, it would help people to provide you with the right kind of answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the table in excel file, you could go to “Site contents” ->click “New”->click “App”->click “Import Spreadsheet”.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Create a list based on a spreadsheet.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa)

If you want to import the table in database, you should create external content type by business connectivity services and Secure Store Services in SharePoint designer 2013. Then create the list from the external content type.

More references:

[Creating an External Content Type with SharePoint Designer.](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/business-connectivity-services/creating-an-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer-reading.cfm)

[Make an External List from a SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity Services and Secure Store.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-an-external-list-from-a-sql-azure-table-with-business-connectivity-services-and-secure-store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95)

[Create an external content type from an OData source in SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-an-external-content-type-from-an-odata-source-in-sharepoint)

[Manage Business Connectivity Service Applications.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-business-connectivity-service-applications-2ced10aa-db9a-4828-a7a5-e47a57c3a823)